# How to redirect from default home page to index page?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Say you have a website example.com. If you were to type example.com into a search bar, you would be taken to the index page of that site. However, this page isn't technically the same as example.com/index.html.

```
var currentPage = window.location.href
```

I use the above JS method in some conditional statements to determine the current page and adjust formatting accordingly, but it is not working because of the discrepancy between example.com and example.com/index.html, so how would I perform this kind of redirection?

Comment: Show us a code sample that actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Better to post your code with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// Similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```